# Passing a variable to sed

Tags: shell, shell-script, sed, quoting, variable-substitution

I cannot not use a shell variable in `sed` in the `$NUMBER` form. I have this line in my shell script:

```
cat shared.txt sed 's/whatever1/$2 ... whatever2/' > shared2.txt
```

The result in `shared2.txt` looks like:

```
...$2....
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 26):

Try using double quote instead of single quote:

```
sed "s/whatever1/$2 ... whatever2/" shared.txt > shared2.txt
```

Comment: My biggest complaint with bash is that simple things like these can trip me up for so long. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

While using double quotes works, there are certain circumstances where this won't give what you want. For example,

```
t="bcd"
echo '123$tbcd' | sed "s/$t$t//"
```

(yes, this is somewhat contrived!). You can avoid this by either escaping certain characters:

```
echo '123$tbcd' | sed "s/\$t$t//"
```

but it is easy to miss this. The safest way, in my opinion, is to surround the variables with double quotes (so that spaces don't brake the sed command) and surround the rest of the string with single quotes (to avoid the necessity of escaping certain characters):

```
echo '123$tbcd' | sed 's/$t'"$t"'//'.
```