# sed command not substituting properly

Tags: linux, sed, osx

in a script job.sh I have this string:

```
/home/myname/code_DEM/ > output.txt
```

that I would like to substitute by:

```
/home/myname/code_DEM/ > output_"$datetime".txt
```

where $datetime is a string that automatically loads the date and time.

I tried to do so using the sed command

```
sed -i 's/"$LINEout"/"$LINEnew"/' job.sh
```

where `$LINEout` is the old string that I want to replace by `$LINEnew` which is the new string (the one with the date and time).

Up to now, I cannot get what I want, I have no change.

PS: if someone has the solution for both Linux and MacOs it would be great: I believe the syntax is slightly different from Linux to Mac for the sed command :)

Comment: you are using single quotes so variables are not passed int sed expression. there are so many questions like this out there that it is difficult to imagine that you actually searched before asking. example : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84063/passing-a-variable-to-sed

Comment: As @rMistero says, `'s/"$LINEout"/"$LINEnew"/'` will produce this exact string. To expand `$LINEout` and `$LINEnew`, you must not use apostrophes, but rather quotes (see maulingjaws' answer). Also, you do realize that `$LINEout` and `$LINEnew` cannot just contain the literal strings you are replacing, right? You need to escape any occurances of `sed`'s syntax. Suppose you want to replace `/a$` with `b`, then the command you use is `sed 's/\/a\$/b/'`, not `sed 's//a$/b/'`.

Comment: use this "s/${LINEout}/${LINEnew}/"

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I'm a beginner in script so thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
sed -i "s|$LINEout|$LINEnew|" job.sh
```

If under macOS you need to specify a backup, so you would have to use this:

```
sed -i "" "s|$LINEout|$LINEnew|" job.sh
```

Examples:

```
echo "foo
bar" > sample
cat sample 
foo
bar

rep=bar
sed -i.bak "s|$rep|baz|" sample
cat sample
foo
baz
cat sample.bak 
foo
bar
```

---

Tested with macOS X 10.11.6 and BSD sed

Comment: ok I just read your answer! Thanks ;)

Comment: @LeChat, use another separator than `/`, or better [make sure the variables are in the proper format for `sed`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129059/how-to-ensure-that-string-interpolated-into-sed-substitution-escapes-all-metac/129063#129063)

Answer (score 0):

Note that BSDs (like Apple OS/X) use `sed -i '' ...` for in-place editing without backup while GNU uses `sed -i ...`. On most other systems, `sed` doesn't support in-place editing.

Both got that from `perl`'s `-i` option. So, for portability, you may want to revert to `perl`, which will also address problems with special characters in the variable:

```
A=$LINEout B=$LINEnew perl -i -pe 's/\Q$ENV{A}\E/$ENV{B}/g' job.sh
```

Answer (score -2):

OK found it. Thank you @maulinglawns for your hits ;)
In fact the separators need to be change so as:

```
sed -i "s:$LINEout:$LINEnew:" job.sh
```

Comment: you'll need `-i.bkp` to work on both Linux and Mac.. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux

Comment: This would point to you having some `/`s in the `$LINEout` and `$LINEnew` variables. See my comment about having to escape the stuff you are passing to `sed`.