# How can one pipe a random string to sed for substitution in a file?

Tags: linux, sed

I've tried this:

```
echo $RANDOM | md5sum | head -c 20 | { read val; sed -i 's/__SALT__/$val/g' app.txt; }
```

But this replaces `__SALT__` with the string `$val` instead of the value in the variable.

Comment: Do note there are only 32768 possible values for salt in this case...

Comment: if you want a sensible salt, you should read `/dev/urandom` instead of using the shell's `$RANDOM`. For a random 80-bit salt, you could use `head -c10 /dev/urandom | md5sum | head -c20`. (Or something with `od` to make the hexdump, since getting the MD5 hash of a random byte string is pretty much unnecessary.)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here: [Passing a variable to sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84063/passing-a-variable-to-sed)

Just needs double quotes:

```
echo $RANDOM | md5sum | head -c 20 | { read val; sed -i "s/__SALT__/$val/g" app.txt; }
```